# Python (WinPython 3.4) in visual studio 2015 (community) throwing KeyError

Tags: python, visual-studio-2013

I'm a visual studio novice trying to use it for Python.

```
print ('hello world')
```

Gives me this on the console:

hello world

KeyError: 6451

Press any key to continue . . .

Any ideas. I don't get this problem using CPython interpreter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if it prints the 'hello world', I would say the whole python part is a success, only the return to Visual studio is not

Maybe should you try a small variation, to see what it gives:

```
print ("hello world")
print ("hello2\nhello3\n")
# comment on last line
```

Comment: thanks. But I gave up on visual studio and went back to Spyder. Just don't have time for env issues. I'll circle back soon.

Comment: Looks like an issue with VS 2015 and scipy. VS 2013 works just fine.
What was I thinking trying to use a release candidate from Microsoft.

Comment: Yes, there is a "sea" change with vs2105, and probably only Python3.5 will work well with it. Problem is Winpython will have to wait for mingw to become compatible, before being released on 3.5.